# Which bit-torrent app has these specific features?

Tags: software-recommendation, torrent-client

I'm searching for an Ubuntu bit-torrent client that has these two features:

1. Start the download when idle (and pause download when user interacts with system)
2. Download files in sequential order

Comment: for the "download when idle", it should be doable from Ubuntu's side, not especially with the app. I'm guessing launching a script when the system idles, or when the screensaver starts, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Qbittorrent client supports the second feature. You can get it here: http://qbittorrent.com